# How do I represent object classification hierarchy in a RDBMS

Tags: database-design, relational

My data, **IF** it would be represented by objects, it would look like:

```
abstract class A{
   int a;
   int b;
   string c;
}

class B inherits A{
  string D;
}

class C inherits A{
  int e;
  int f;
}
```

My question: Do I create a separate table for entities B and C,
Or do I create one main table, and for each entity type I do different joins to fetch the data.
In the real world, I will have around 15 similar fields for all entities, and about 1-3 unique field for each entity.
I expect a max of 100K records.

Any insights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find no shortage of opinions on this topic. Many people advocate [concrete table inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html), where (as you describe in your first option) you define the data explicitly in each table.

Given your second statement, I would **not** recommend this pattern. I would go with the idea of having a "main" table representing your parent and auxiliary tables representing the children. You may want to include a type identifier of some kind in your main table in order to indicate what sort of entity it is, but this may or may not be necessary. At a minimum, you need something like...

```
tableA
(
    ID (primary),
    A,
    B,
    C
)

tableB
(
    ID (primary and foreign->table_A),
    D
)

tableC
(
    ID (primary and foreign->table_A),
    E,
    F
)
```

Answer (score 3):

table_a contains all similar fields,table_B and table_c contain the unique fields

```
table_A
   PKa
   a int
   b int
   c string


table_B
  PKb
  FKa
  D string


table_C
  PKc
  FKa
  e int
  f int
```