# mysql - referencing one foreign key to multiple possible primary keys

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I'd like to set up the following database scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `points` (
  `po_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `po_north` INT,
  `po_east` INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`po_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lines`(
  `li_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `li_from` INT NOT NULL,
  `li_to` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`li_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`li_from`) REFERENCES points(`po_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`li_to`) REFERENCES points(`po_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now I want to set up a third table, that sores some metadata like who created or altered a point or a line:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `metadata` (
  `me_type` ENUM('point','line') NOT NULL,
  `me_type_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `me_permissions` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `me_created_by` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `me_created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `me_last_modified_by` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `me_last_modified_by` DATETIME NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

My first approach was to set an `ENUM` with two types (points and lines). But the problem is still, that I cannot properly reference a foreign key to one of the tables. Is there any recommended solution for such problem in MySQL?

BTW: 
The fields for `me_created_by` and `me_last_modified_by` shall reference to a table storing some user data.

Comment: Can your tables Points and Lines reference Metadata instead, i.e. put a foreign key 'metadata_id' in both of these tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tables `points` and `lines` should contain a foreign key to `metadata` – not the other way around. Doing so will save you from defining any more complicated table setups. Using this approach, a single `metadata`-entry could be re-used several times for many different points or lines. This isn't even MySQL specific but a general, normalized database structure.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't think about that way. This seems to be the easiest kind of solution to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: @mgr This is the "default" way in relational databases. You should read something about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 1):

Your case appears to be yet another instance of the design pattern known as "generalization specialization"  or perhaps "table design for class inheritance".

If you think of points and lines as classes of objects, they are both subclasses of some more general class of objects.  I'm not sure what name to give the superclass in this case.  Here's one of several previous questions that address the same issue.

[Extending classes in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875116/extending-classes-in-the-database)

Fowler gives an extensive treatment of the subject.  Your case has an added wrinkle, because you are dealing with metadata.  But that need not alter the design.  You need a third table, which I'll call "Items" for lack of a better term.  The key, "it_id" would be assigned an auto number,  and you would add an item every time you add either a point or a line.  The two columns "po_id" and "li_id" would not be assigned an auto number.  Instead they would be foreign keys, referencing "it_id" in the Items table.

The references to points or lines in the metadata table would then be references to "items" and you could use that information to find information about points or lines as the case may be.

How helpful this is depends on what you are trying to do with the metadata.

Comment: That solution is quite interesting to me, I'll follow your suggestions an read through some of the given articles. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can do this using a trigger, you need to trigger an event that can create reference key for either point or line before you insert a record based on respective tables

Comment: I think mgr is asking how to structure the database schema so that a table can have a foreign key to a primary field in one table OR another different table. Or do you mean to use a trigger to check referential integrity instead of a constraint?